# React-color ChromePicker doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-color

I'm using [react-color](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-color) and after following [this tutorial](https://casesandberg.github.io/react-color/#api-color) I had implemented a ChromePicker.

How should it work:

- open the ChromePicker
- select a color using the hue bar and/or the "big square"
- after the ChromePicker is closed I want to update the color value on an object that is on props

So far it works like this:

- it opens when its button is clicked
- selecting the color is not working properly. When I click on the hue and drag that small circle sideways the color is changing ( I know this because there is a `this.state.color`) but the circle remains the same position. Also, I would expect to load on the "big square" the now color palette but it's not doing it. If I click in the square to select a color, it works similar to the hue bar. The circle remains on the same position even if the value is changing.
- the value is saved but also doesn't work fine: that request is called multiple times, every time the color is changed. I want it to change only after I select a color and I exit the ChromePicker (by clicking somewhere outside of it) and I was thinking that `onChangeComplete` would do that.

Here is a screenshot of it:

[image]

Why is the ChromePicker so badly? Is there a way to solve it? And also, I would like to save the new color on Company only after the ChromePicker is closed (it seems that `onChangeComplete` is not triggered by that)

This is the code:

```
 import React from 'react';
    import { Button, Icon } from 'semantic-ui-react';
    import { ChromePicker } from 'react-color';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import { Creators } from '../../actions';
    
    
    class Banner extends React.PureComponent {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          displayColorPicker: false,
        };
      }
    
      handleClick = () => {
        this.setState({ displayColorPicker: true });
      };
    
      handleClose = () => {
        this.setState({ displayColorPicker: false });
      };
    
      handleChangeComplete = colors => {
        const {
          name,
          color,
        } = this.state;
        this.setState({ color: colors.hex });
        const { updateCompany } = this.props; // company is the entity from props that is updated
                                              // it contains 2 values, its name and its color
        updateCompany(this.props.company._id, {
          name,
          color,
        });
      };
    
    
    
      render() {
        this.props.color.color.color = this.state.color;
        const popover = { // this is not essential, it's some styling for the picker
          position: 'absolute',
          zIndex: '2',
        };
        const cover = { // same as for popover
          position: 'fixed',
          top: '0px',
          right: '0px',
          bottom: '0px',
          left: '0px',
        };
        const {company } = this.props; // gets the company from props
        return (
          <div className="banner-container settings-banner">   
     
      //the below div with its style is updating in real time when the color is changed 
                  <div style={{ backgroundColor: this.state.color }}>              
                    <div>
                      <Button
                        className="select-color-btn"
                        onClick={this.handleClick}>
                        Select a color
                      </Button>
                      {this.state.displayColorPicker ? (
                        <div style={popover}>
                          <div
                            style={cover}
                            onClick={this.handleClose}
                            onKeyDown={this.handleClick}
                            role="button"
                            tabIndex="0"
                            aria-label="Save"
                          />
                          <ChromePicker
                            color={this.props.company.color}
                            onChangeComplete={this.handleChangeComplete}
                          />
                        </div>
                      ) : null}
                    </div>
                  </div>
            
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    
    const mapStateToProps = state => ({
      company: state.companies.selectedCompany,
    });
    
    const mapDispatchToProps = {
      updateCompany: Creators.updateCompanyRequest,
    };
    
    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Banner);
```